# Change parent element background when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, css

I'm looking to change the background colour of the label #cont when the checkbox below is checked.

Is there any way to do this with javascript?

```html
<label id="cont">
  <span>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </span>
</label>
```

Comment: no. you need javascript.

Comment: See if this article fits your needs using :checked psuedo-class https://www.sitepoint.com/building-style-switcher-with-pure-css-using-checked/